# Why does (Py)ZeroMQ open so many Unix socket files?

Tags: python, zeromq, pyzmq

I tried to monitor the number of open Unix socket files with `lsof -U | wc -l` while I executed this code:

```py
>>> import zmq
# 1375 Unix socket files
>>> c = zmq.Context()
# 1377 Unix socket files
>>> s = c.socket(zmq.PUSH)
# 1383 Unix socket files
>>> s.close()
# 1381 Unix socket files
>>> c.destroy()
# 1375 Unix socket files
```

Why is that? I would expect a TCP/IPC socket file being opened when I connected the socket, but what about those files before even connecting?

It seems they are all of type "STREAM":

[image]

### Update

See @gdlmx's answer for a useful script to reproduce this issue.

It seems if you use Conda to install `pyzmq` everything works as expected. I, however, am still interested in knowing why it would not work if you install `pyzmq` with `pip`, which I would consider the standard way to install the package.

Steps to reproduce:

With Conda:

```
conda create -n foo python=3.6
conda activate foo
pip install pyzmq
python test_script.py
```

With Python's `venv`:

```
python3.6 -m venv venv
source ./venv/bin/activate
pip install pyzmq
python test_script.py
```

Comment: TCP almost always uses SOCK_STREAM and UDP uses SOCK_DGRAM. So `type=STREAM` most likely means "socket communicating over tcp".

Comment: @Clonk The question is why. I mean, there are 8 of those socket files but I only created a single ZMQ socket and I did not even bound/connected it.

Comment: There are several Unix socket per ZMQ socket. There are also Unix socket in the ZMQ context. How much exactly is dependent many thing notably the argument you give to the constructor of your context.

Comment: I'm guessing this is necessary for the internal mechanism of ZMQ such as PUB / SUB mechanism, Proxy, pipeline, router / dealer etc... that may requires multiple socket to implement. Using a pool of socket reusable may be to increase performance ? (total number of Unix socket doesn't appear to be linked to the number of zmq socket).

Comment: @Clonk If that was the case it does not seem to be the best thing for performance. What if I bound/connected the socket using `inproc` transport? (for communication between threads) That would not require socket files (like it would for IPC/TCP). Let us see if someone can shed some light on this, as I am just guessing, like you. :-)

Comment: Yes it seems strange. I wonder if the same thing would hold true in C++

Comment: This sort of low-level discussion is probably a better fit for the [zmq mailing list](http://zeromq.org/docs:mailing-lists) - I know in the past some of the core contributors have been active there (they have here as well, on occasion, but that's probably a more reliable venue).

Answer (score 4):

I recommend to rerun your test with plain python or ipython (without console). Please also limit the counting to a single process with `lsof -p <pid>` to exclude unnecessary interference from other processes in your machine (those 1375 Unix socket files in your test).

Here is a simple test script:

```py
import os
pid = os.getpid()
count=0

def lsof():
    global count
    count += 1
    print(count,':')
    os.system("lsof -p {0:d} 2>/dev/null | grep -E 'unix|IPv4|IPv6'".format(pid)) # -U doesn't work togeter with -p option
    # Alternatively, you can use "lsof -U 2>/dev/null | grep -E {0:d}"
    # but only unix socket file will be listed.

import zmq
c = zmq.Context();lsof()
tcp = c.socket(zmq.PUSH);lsof()
unix = c.socket(zmq.PUSH);lsof()

print('--- To bind  ---')
tcp.bind('tcp://127.0.0.1:19413');lsof()
unix.bind('ipc://filename');lsof()

print('--- To close ---')
tcp.close();lsof()
unix.close();lsof()
```

Below is the test result in my environment (python 3.6.6, pyzmq 17.1.2, w/ Anaconda in CentOS 7).

```
1 :
2 :
3 :
--- To bind  ---
4 :
ZMQbg/1 284018 gdlmx   13u     IPv4           49443178      0t0      TCP localhost:19413 (LISTEN)
5 :
ZMQbg/1 284018 gdlmx   13u     IPv4           49443178      0t0      TCP localhost:19413 (LISTEN)
ZMQbg/1 284018 gdlmx   14u     unix 0xffff9cd6c5bf4800      0t0 49443204 filename
--- To close ---
6 :
ZMQbg/1 284018 gdlmx   14u     unix 0xffff9cd6c5bf4800      0t0 49443204 filename
7 :
```

I've used python and ipython to run the script and got the same result.

To conclude, the socket file or network port is open only when `socket.bind` is called. No other socket is open by the python/ipython processes during my tests.

### Update

In response to the update of PO:

The abnormal (unexpected) behavior is probably caused by the pre-built binaries bundled in the pyzmq package on PyPI. `pip install pyzmq` will download that [distribution tar ball](https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/91/f5/c9bef3768d6f8d71aae8f44f1ddbee90162dad909560fa6c13e4872e28c9/pyzmq-18.0.1-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl) from PyPI, which contains the following pre-compiled binary files:

```
zmq/backend/cython:
    _device.so  _proxy_steerable.so  constants.so  error.so    socket.so
    _poll.so    _version.so          context.so    message.so  utils.so

zmq/.libs:
    libzmq-39117701.so.5.2.1         libsodium-72341b7d.so.23.2.0
```

To be compatible with as many Linux OS as possible, these binaries are built within a very old OS (CentOS 5) in a docker environment called [manylinux](https://github.com/pypa/manylinux).

Anaconda uses a different approach to pre-build the binaries and contains all dependencies in the `conda/envs` folder. So their binaries are built in a relatively up-to-date environment.

I tested the PyPI's binaries on my CentOS 7 machine with the above script. I can confirm that ZeroMQ opens some "background" sockets (2 sockets after context creation and 8 after the first socket creation). Although my tests below show that they are used for inter-threads communication for the internal mechanisms of ZeroMQ, it's better to directly ask the maintainers of the [PyPI package](https://pypi.org/project/pyzmq).

You may also try to force `pip`/`setuptools` to build ZeroMQ for your OS:

```
sudo yum install libzmq3-devel #  RHEL-based
pip install --no-use-wheel pyzmq 
# Use `--no-binary :all:` instead of `--no-use-wheel` in pip >= 10.0.0
```

This might get rid of the background sockets, if that's what you want.

### What's the purpose of the background sockets?

ZeroMQ internally uses multiple threads for the IO operation. The number of threads can be configured via [IO_THREADS](http://zguide.zeromq.org/php:chapter2#I-O-Threads). I find that this number affects the number of sockets in use. Test it with

```
num_io_threads = int(sys.argv[1])
c = zmq.Context()
c.set(zmq.IO_THREADS,num_io_threads)
s = c.socket(zmq.PUSH)
lsof()
```

You will find that `number_of_sockets` = `6 + 2 * num_io_threads`. Thus, I postulate that the ZeroMQ binaries from PyPI internally use sockets for inter-threads communication between the main thread and the worker/IO threads.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you try and install `pyzmq` within your virtual environment with `pip` instead of Conda? In example: `conda create -n foo python=3.6.6; conda activate foo; pip install pyzmq; python test_script.py`.

Comment: You can also try without Conda and create a virtual environment using `python3.6 -m venv venv; source venv/bin/activate; pip install pyzmq; python test_script.py`. It seems installing the package with `pip`/`conda` makes a difference.

Comment: PS: Updated my question noting that the issue can be reproduced by installing `pyzmq` with `pip` and recommending to use your provided test script.

Comment: Would you mind removing the iPython-related section from your answer? I think it only adds noise as the issue can be reproduced no matters if you use iPython or Python.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I've updated my answer accordingly. The problem is caused by the bundled binaries in the PyPI package. So there's not so much space for me to dig into.

Comment: Sorry, I thought the full bounty (not half) was awarded automatically when you had 2+ votes. I just learnt that. :-(